# MacBook Pro wireless speed slow after OS update

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

After the OS update, my wireless speeds have dropped to a crawl.  around 350 to 500 kps on my home wlan.    Every other device on my wlan runs between 6 and 10 mbs.  I've only found posts about deleting the wireless network, recycling the router and then creating a new connection.   Obviously I don't have access to every wireless router I connect to in able to do this and the connection is consistently slow no matter what network.  Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Any idea which version of the OS you update to? I had an issue with Snow Leopard previously where an update caused my Wi-Fi to connect at only 11Mbps when it used to be at 54Mbps. Apparently, my issue was due to a wi-fi driver was installed together with the update. I had to upgrade to Lion to have that fixed.

Comment: One common thing I've seen is these speed issues happen shortly before a new version of the OS comes out.

Answer (score 1):

I would first try resetting your PRAM, then create a new network location.

From Apple:

> **Resetting PRAM and NVRAM**
>
> 1. Shut down the computer.
> 2. Locate the following keys on the keyboard: Command, Option, P, and R. You will need to hold these keys down simultaneously in step 4.
> 3. Turn on the computer.
> 4. Press and hold the Command-Option-P-R keys. You must press this key combination before the gray screen appears.
> 5. Hold the keys down until the computer restarts and you hear the startup sound for the second time.
> 6. Release the keys.

Once you've done so, delete your network locations in System Preferences and create a new, fresh location.